# How do I avoid Error normalizePath with read_excel in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I was trying to import table from excel (xlsx) to my R, but I get an error

```
Warning message: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="Data_202310.xlsx": Access is denied
```

The file was imported using:

```
read_excel("Data_202310.xlsx")
```

Does anyone know why this problem occurs and how can avoid this?

Comment: The two first things that come to my mind are 1) that the file might be open in Excel already, if thats the case try closing it and rerunning the code, 2) if that doesnt work try running R (or rstudio if you're using that) as Admin. If that doesnt fix the problem we'll probably need to more information on the folder structure, the file and the code you're using.

Comment: This is almost always due to the file being opened in another application (e.g., Excel) and being "locked" by the OS. Closing that application and then reattempting to open the file in R should fix the issue. I urge _against_ running R or RStudio as Admin, that is fixing a gnat with a sledge hammer and comes with other consequences (most minor, but still). If closing Excel does not fix it then you have other problems, likely filesystem/permissions based, and therefore unlikely to have anything to do with R or RStudio itself.